# Getting User information from url

Tags: php, asp.net, url

Im building a system that will detect Users, Pages in site from Url like below:

```
www.site.com/user    or www.site.com/page
```

I want to know that : is this possible without creating directory with name 'user' or 'page' to detect the user or page.

```
page and user are unique name in site.
```

for example : facebook uses this method to assign unique address to pages like image below:
[image]

What is the solution for this problem.

if the question is not clear comment to clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a framework of some kind, you should be able to handle this with whatever routing mechanism that framework provides. So the answer depends on what tools you're using. Take a look at [CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter) and [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/) for example.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do use a Framework. First of, every username has to be unique for you to be able to have such functionality on your site.

Take a look at this tutorial on how to do that:

http://www.codexperience.co.za/post/hiding-url-parameters-names-using-zend-routers

This might do the trick

Answer (score -2):

AFAIK this is done with a .htaccess that redirects `domain/user` to your script `index.php?arg1=user` (or whatever) so if you look at .htaccess-redirects, that should help to move forward...

Comment: While this can be done with Apache configuration (which people, all too often, forget is better placed in a standard configuration file than in a .htaccess file), a redirect isn't the answer as the browser would go to the new URL. You'd need a rewrite instead if you were going to handle it at the HTTP server level.